# Data Validation based on query results

Tags: validation, ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I need to restrict users from double-booking tasks in the same time slot.  I have a simple scheduling table.

**Schedule_tbl**

```
PK ScheduleEntry
Date
EmployeeID
StartTime
EndTime
TaskID
```

On the form, the user goes through some combo boxes to filter down to a smaller subset of tasks.  Once the task is chosen, they then select the date, a start time, and a stop time that they will be working on that task.  What I need to figure out is how to prevent the user from double booking a time-slot.

For instance, if they book 2/28/2017, from 9-3, then they should not be able to book another task from 11-1, or 12-5...anything that overlaps what they have already scheduled.

I'm not sure where to go, or what things to consider.

Comment: you need to validate the data before it is actually inserted into the table. if the insert is done by clicking a button, then validation should be a simple query that checks for the availability and never writes to the table if a slot is taken. if the data is being inserted into the table as the users enter them, or it is already bound to the table and you allow data entry, then you still need the query to check an entry already exists, but the rollback would be handled differently

Comment: My need is how to use that query as the validation.  Do I create an "On_Click" event that takes the data from the form trying to enter, compares it to a query, and throws an error if an entry exists?  Or is there another method I need to consider?

Comment: that depends on how the data is saved. do the users currently click on a button to save the data, or are they saved as they enter data on the form. if prior, then you don't need a new button, you just need to edit the code behind that button, and where you would insert that query check. if latter, then its handled a bit differently